# Bug with a cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, p5.js

I am currently making a Flappybird game in Javacript and right now I am implementing a cookie to store the highscore. But here is the problem, the cookie is always undefined and won't change.

So that nobody is confused, I should say that I use the Framework p5.js, which helps me to draw stuff. The code is on my gitHub repository (https://github.com/HaasStefan/challengeRepo/tree/master/FlappyBird). The main code is in the file named sketch.js, but here are some snippets:

First, this is where I initialize everything, and also the cookie:

```
function setup() {
createCanvas(400, 600);
bird = new Bird();
menu = new Menu();
pipes.push(new Pipe());

alert(navigator.cookieEnabled);

if (typeof (document.cookie == "undefined"))
  document.cookie = "highscore=0; expires=Sun, 1 Dec 2030 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
}
```

Next we have the part, where the cookie is read and changed:

```
let str = document.cookie.split(';');
highscore = str[0].split('=')[1];
if (score > highscore) {
  highscore = score;
  document.cookie = "highscore=" + highscore + "; expires=Sun, 1 Dec 2030 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
}
```

I really hope you can help me with this problem, because I have no idea what the bug is. Thank you!

Comment: `if(typeof ...)` will always execute as typeof returns a string that is a truthy value

Comment: @jro so, i should make a strict equal (===)? But this won't fix the problem

Comment: You can use the code you have for getting the highscore then check if its undefined

Comment: You have the parentheses wrong. It should be `if (typeof document.cookie == "undefined")`

Comment: But that's the wrong way to tell whether you've set the cookie. There might be some other cookies, but not the `highscore` cookie.

Comment: Guys, this doesn't help. And no, this question has not already been answered, because this is very specific. The cookie does not even set the value, even if I use the sugggested code from the other questions. and changing the paranthese didn't change a thing. @Barmar I only set the highscore cookie, so it must be the only cookie

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] that focus just on writing and then reading the cookie, without any of the extra code?

Comment: Your code to read the cookie doesn't look correct. You're never searching `str` for the entry that begins with `highscore=`.

Comment: But I've reopened the question.

Comment: `document.cookie` will never be undefined, it will be an empty string if no cookies have been set. Use the functions in the linked question to read and set your cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was already mentioned in the comments, the first problem is with the if condition

```
if (typeof (document.cookie == "undefined"))
```

which must be written as

```
if (typeof document.cookie != "undefined")
```

The next problem is with reading the value from the 'highscore' cookie. Assuming there are several other cookies, the way to read its value should be:

```
var highscore = ('; '+document.cookie).split('; highscore=').pop().split(";").shift();
```

The result of the line above is of type string so you need to convert it to int before doing any comparisons.

```
highscore = parseInt(highscore)
```

To sum things up:

```
if (typeof document.cookie != "undefined") {
  document.cookie = "highscore=0; expires=Sun, 1 Dec 2030 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
}
```

and then

```
let str = ('; '+document.cookie).split('; highscore=').pop().split(";").shift();
highscore = str ? parseInt(str) : 0;
if (score > highscore) {
  highscore = score;
  document.cookie = "highscore=" + highscore + "; expires=Sun, 1 Dec 2030 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
}
```